# [PYTHON]-how to put new line on data if it's on loop (TXT FILE)

Tags: python, file, loops, text

How to put every line on loop a new line? 
I tried using \n but it doesn't work

```
f = open('text.txt','w')
f.write('HEADER\n')

for x in hr_lines:
    f.write('PHP')
    f.write('100\n')
```

**Current Output:**

```
HEADERPHP100PHP100
```

**Expected Output**

```
HEADER
PHP100
PHP100
```

Comment: `f.write('PHP')` ==> `f.write('PHP\n')`

Comment: Just tested the code and it works fine for me. When I use "cat text.txt" on the command line I get the expected output. How are you checking your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this is working

```
with open('text.txt','w') as f:
     f.write('HEADER\n')

     for x in hr_lines:
         f.write('PHP')
         f.write('100\n')
```

Also try to open the txt file with a different editor

Answer (score 0):

The same code seems to be working for me

```
f = open('text.txt','w')
f.write('HEADER\n')

for x in hr_lines:
    f.write('PHP')
    f.write('100\n')
```

Comment: which version of python and text editor are you using?